# Don't understand why this overflows revert

Tags: overflow, timelock, time, revert

I have a timelock on an ERC20 contract, from year 0 to 9, it works until year 4, but from year 5 onwards it reverts. It fails both on minting and checking (Using 52 seconds intead of weeks for testing):

```
constructor() ERC20("Coin", "C") {        
    deploymentTime = block.timestamp;        
} 

function checkMintDate(uint8 year) public view returns (uint256){
    return deploymentTime + 52 seconds * year;
} 

function mint(uint8 year) public onlyOwner {        
    require (year <= 9, "cannot claim for more than 10 years");
    require(block.timestamp >= deploymentTime + 52 seconds * year, "Not that year yet");        
    require(!yearClaimed[year], "you already claimed that year");
    yearClaimed[year] = true;
    _mint(msg.sender, yearlyMintAmount);
}
```

When deployed to the testnet, remix gives this data, which is the overflow one:

"code":
"3",
"message":
"execution reverted",
"output": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011"

Any ideas?, thanks!

Comment: If I change the "seconds" sufix to "years", the checkMintDate function passes with all the numbers, and returns the correct unix dates. But it keeps failing with "seconds", wtf...

Comment: It s normal it s conversion problem:
52 weeks = 1 year,
31536000 seconds = 1year
But I m sure you get it

And to help you to understand why it s passing in "seconds" with different value of "Year". Then you must consider :  52 seconds * year as minutes (rounded)
And so, to pass the test with year = 5, you just have to wait more than 5 minutes

Comment: I wait for more than 5 minutes, and it gives the overflow error on remix, the block explorer gives even less information. But it doesn't give the failed required statement of "Not that year yet".                                      https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x79980625b198bc286d4cbefa430caabefb67bc670e613e900c14415ee9aad435

Comment: Maybe it is a Polygon bug?, I'll deploy to other testnet later today.

Answer (score 0):

So on the first analyse, you didnt convert correctly in year

```
function checkMintDate(uint8 year) public view returns (uint256){
return deploymentTime + 52 weeks * year;}
```

and for the require the same:

```
require(block.timestamp >= deploymentTime + 52 weeks * year, "Not that year yet");
```

---

For the error :
0x11: If an arithmetic operation results in underflow or overflow outside of an unchecked { ... } block.

So it s a type conversion issue Uint8 max value is 256 but 5*52 is over 260.

To solve the problem: the best practice is to send the parameter in uint256, it's costing less gas and avoid this error.

If not just then cast : ....52 seconds *  uint256(year)...

Comment: I know that for year it should be 52 weeks, but, I'm testing with 52 seconds, and it fails from year 5 onwards. This is not the final state of the contract, I won't use seconds on livenet, but I want to understand why it fails with seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in another forum, had to change year to uint256:

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/dont-understand-this-overflow-in-my-timelock/33075/4